# How to undo "Also block previews from this website in the future"?

Tags: slack

When sharing a URL via Slack, a preview appears.  You can click on the `X` next to the preview to remove the preview.  This shows the following form:

[image: Remove previewe? modal dialog]

The checkbox option labeled "Also block previews from this website in the future" is channel specific.  This option is channel-specific.  Meaning you can block previews for direct messages to Person1 but not Person2.

After blocking previews for a direct message channel, how would you go about unblocking previews for that channel?

Comment: Welcome to [webapps.se]. Slack Help has [Share links and set preview preferences](https://slack.com/help/articles/204399343-Share-links-and-set-preview-preferences) and possible other related help articles. Please search Slack resources for end-users like Slack Help. If you need further help share what you found and why it didn't meet your needs.